# Can you put a Canvas instance inside a jQuery gallery?

Tags: jquery, canvas, kineticjs

I've made several simple particle and game examples using Canvas and KineticJS and I was thinking about the using a slider like Nivo to show them off. First thoughts are that I would need to redraw each canvas on transition of the slider, but I was just wondering if anyone has tried this already with any success or failures and if it's feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 var mystage = stage.toImage(config);
```

to convert the canvas to an image, then you can transition images.

But if you want the whole stage saved as an object you just do:

```
 var json = stage.toJSON();
```

and that saves your stage for reloading later, which you can do with:

```
 var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```